# Why I couldn't disable stylecop rule in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, stylecop

I have this stylecop settings files in my project directory.

```
<StyleCopSettings Version="105">
  <GlobalSettings>
    <StringProperty Name="MergeSettingsFiles">NoMerge</StringProperty>
  </GlobalSettings>
  <Analyzers>
    <Analyzer AnalyzerId="StyleCop.CSharp.OrderingRules">
      <Rules>
        <Rule Name="UsingDirectivesMustBePlacedWithinNamespace">
          <RuleSettings>
            <BooleanProperty Name="Enabled">False</BooleanProperty>
          </RuleSettings>
        </Rule>
      </Rules>
      <AnalyzerSettings />
    </Analyzer>
  </Analyzers>
</StyleCopSettings>
```

[image]

It should disable warnings but is still showing 1200(UsingDirectivesMustBePlacedWithinNamespace) warnings in the error list window. This obviously should work but why it is not working? What I'm missing?

Comment: StyleCop? Or StyleCop Analyzers? Can you include a screenshot of the Error List?

Comment: @mjwills I've added screenshot. I'm not sure which but I use Stylecop extension to run stylecop.

Comment: That is StyleCop Analyzers. I'd suggest reading the docs - https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1200.md https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/Configuration.md#configuring-stylecop-analyzers .